# How to display username from sql data base matching session id

Tags: php, mysql, session

So far I have tried everything such as selecting `$_SESSION['username']` and `$_SESSION['user_name']`, I even tried to say with `mysqli_*`. There IS `session_start();` at the top!

I am trying to display the `user_name` row corresponding to the user's session ID or the `user_id` column in my SQL database. [This image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLfJU.png) is the account page I want to show the username on.

---

### Files:

> index.php

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">
        <p>Account Info:</p>
    </div>
    <hr color="white">
    <div class="accinfo">
        <p style='display: inline;'>Username:
        <?php
            $_SESSION['user_name'] = "xxx";

            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "kurticlan_forum");
            $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='user_name'");
            $result = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
            $username = $_SESSION['user_name'];

            echo $_SESSION['user_name']
        ?>
        </p>
        <p>User Number: <?php   echo $_SESSION['id'] ?></p>
        <p>Password: *** |
            <a style="text-decoration: none; color: blue; font-size: 12px" href="/account/changepassword.php">Change Password</a>
        </p>
        <br />
        <p style="display: inline;">Account Picture:</p><img
    </div>
</div>
```

> MySQL Database
>   [View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPbBp.png)

---

Before anyone says "This is a duplicate post" because I know atleast someone will... This is all my code, I know there are loads of posts exactly like this but none of those solutions in those posts have helped me... I have tried the code without the first  **$_SESSION['user_name'] = "xxx";**  it just says that the variable **"user_name"** is undefined. I have not a clue what is happening or why it is not working! I have also tried the whole $row thing but it says it is undefined also.

Comment: What's purpose of this SQL condition : WHERE user_name='user_name'?

Comment: **1st :** you need to start the session before using it `session_start();` **2nd :** `WHERE user_name='user_name'` what you trying to do with this ?

Comment: I don't know... I saw that helped someone else with a similar question so I though it might help me?

Comment: The code as shown makes very little sense. You can not just substitute 
 copy&paste of stuff you see elsewhere, for your own logical thinking of what steps your script has to perform and in what order. If you have that little experience how to properly structure a script and get at least the basic logic laid out correctly, you should not be working on anything even closely related to any user login functionality - chances that you mess something up regarding the basic security are just immense. You should use an existing solution in such a case, and not try and roll your own.

Comment: @CBroe I have hashed and salted the password, I know this is not encryption but it works and it is safer than storing raw text passwords. I like to solve problems and roll on my own plus I have spent quite a long time trying to develop my own system just so I can say that I developed it myself. Thanks anyway

Comment: _“I am trying to display the user_name row corresponding to the user's session ID or the user_id column in my SQL database.”_ - where are you trying to select anything based on an ID here? There only thing you have shown is a query that selects records where the column `user_name` contains the _text value_ `user_name` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem to my problem was that in my login php script:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbh.php'; //just connects to database

$user_name = $_POST['username'];
$user_pass = $_POST['password'];
$msg = "Your username or password is incorrect!";

$salt = "aJd32".$user_pass."iki9P";

$hash_pwd = hash('sha512', $salt); 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$user_name' AND user_pass='$hash_pwd'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg');</script>";
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

} else {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['user_id']; //I saw this row!
    //I added rows here
    header("Location: /account/");
}
?>
```

Then added these rows!

```
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $row['user_name'];
$_SESSION['user_email'] = $row['user_email'];
$_SESSION['user_date'] = $row['user_date'];
```

---

Then in my index.php I just did `echo $_SESSION['user_name'];` and it worked! I now have a working script that displays the logged in users name from the sql database!

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to start session on header as

`session_start();`

as you have defined default value of session user_name

`$_SESSION['user_name'] = "xxx";`

your query will be like this.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='".$_SESSION['user_name']."'");
```

Comment: I have changed the query to this. Session has started and I have commented out the `$_SESSION['user_name'] = "xxx";` so it wont show "xxx" after username. Instead of coming up with an error, I now have a blank area, so we're getting somewhere.

Comment: if you will comment that it means there is no any session value named user_name so you will get blank area. uncomment it and refresh page.

Comment: you have to define session while login. give session a value when user logged in. then you can access that value untill you destroy the session.

Comment: Uncommented and it just displays "xxx"

Comment: yes because you have printed it using echo. if you want record then comment your echo. add this line `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);` and print it as `print_r($row);`

Answer (score 0):

**Re written your Code.. Replace this with your old code and give me a Update.**

```
   <div class="container">
        <div style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">
            <p>Account Info:</p>
        </div>
        <hr color="white">
        <div class="accinfo">
            <p style='display: inline;'>Username:
<?php
                $sess_username= $_SESSION['user_name'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "kurticlan_forum";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}    
$sql = "SELECT user_name, user_id FROM users WHERE user_name= $sess_username";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $username = $row["user_name"];
        $id = $row["user_id"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);

    if($username == $sess_username)
    {

echo $username;
            ?>
            </p>
            <p>User Number: <?php   echo $id; ?></p>
            <p>Password: *** |
                <a style="text-decoration: none; color: blue; font-size: 12px" href="/account/changepassword.php">Change Password</a>
            </p>
            <br />
            <p style="display: inline;">Account Picture:</p><img
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

But your is not the exact solution you need Understand what you are exactly doing. always make a function to check islogin!!
and call it 1st in line your php
That function must need to check username post with session match.

then you can proceed normal code. I was just Re written you code in working status as you given.. and Please use Prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you for helping! I copied and pasted that exact code replacing everything else I had in there: https://imgur.com/a/juOoI

Comment: So you started the session already. Replace the code i have re written and VOTE ME UP..

Comment: Yes. This was error. `Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in D:\Program Installs\XAMPP\htdocs\account\index.php on line 90`

Line 90 is `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {`

I also got `Notice: Undefined variable: username in D:\Program Installs\XAMPP\htdocs\account\index.php on line 98`

Line 98 is: `if($username == $_SESSION['user_name'])`

Comment: Now i have Re written..replace and give a try again.

Comment: First it said access not allowed because password was wrong, updated that and then it came up with this error: `Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in D:\Program Installs\XAMPP\htdocs\account\index.php on line 101` - Line 101 is: `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {` - Nothing else below the php code shows either, just "0 results"

Comment: Would like to know ur database has the users? if there is not username and userid it can show the error. for me it shows output.

Comment: But we are searching for the user xxx right? have you changed name to something or Have you already set the username? i now will remove the force setting of session. check it again. Now the code will get already session for `$_SESSION['user_name']` so set a session some other page matching the database

Comment: I'm thinking maybe it could work something like this: `if($row['user_name'] == $_SESSION['id']) { echo $_SESSION['user_name']; }`

Comment: he don't have username stored in session. still he wants to get user_name. which is impossible. `first you must have to define a value to session to access it. you have to do it while login.`

Comment: No its wrong you are checking for row username matches the userid = error Kindly replace my recent edited code.

Comment: @AshishPatel i already asking him and if he is testing he need to get a DB matching username for test . but he is using xxx to test. and this is malpractice he need to use a separate function to check the username and password matches and then create a session for them. then you need check islogin function to check the session and db username matches.

Comment: my example code wasn't supposed to work, just example. @AshishPatel is correct, I do not have anything previously stored, no idea how to do that.

Comment: Guys!!! I analyzed my login code and I realised that I has a line `$_SESSION['id'] = $row['user_id'];` after they successfully logged in, so I added a new line saying `$_SESSION['user_name'] = $row['user_name'];` and now it's working! Thanks for the help people!

Comment: @Andrew thats what i already said. you need to define it before following code executes or a function to check while login. anyway you got a working one.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did see you say that but I didn't know what you meant. I know I could have asked but, uhh... I don't have an excuse but it's working now. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Okay okay. Create a public funtion to check islogged in. to check on everywhere whether session expired.